# Spring Integration Java DSL: In the error channel database logger is not working

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have my database logger `myDatabaseLogger` which doesn't do anything in the `errorChannel` channel. The `System.out.println` command is working in the `errorChannel` channel.

My database logger `myDatabaseLogger` works in other flows.

How to get the my database logger `myDatabaseLogger` working in the `errorChannel` channel?

Here is my code:

```
    @Autowired
@Qualifier("errorChannel")
private PublishSubscribeChannel errorChannel;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(errorChannel)
            .handle(myDatabaseLogger, "log")
            .handle(message -> System.out
                    .println("The error happened:" + ((MessagingException) message.getPayload()).getMessage()))
            .get();
}
```

Edit:

Sorry about delay, just came from holiday.

The `myDatabaseLogger` class is simple Java class which writes to the database with the repository, which extends `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`. In the method `errorHandlingFlow` no lines are written to the database.

I will later use the `DEBUG` logging and try to investigate this more.

Comment: It's still not working after you added the `from(errorChannel)`? Turn on DEBUG logging and watch the message flow.

Comment: I marked your question as "Unclear what you're asking" because we really don't know what is that your `myDatabaseLogger`. And what does it mean for your " doesn't do anything"? What do you expect from it to be done? That is fully your own component and your question is really has to start from it. Otherwise we are not able to help you. Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DEBUG logger could be used here to find cause of the problem.